# How to get windows username with JSF?

Tags: jsf, ntlm

For authentication purpose, I want to get the windows username of my users when they access to the index page. I will use this windows username to check a database and if this user is knowned, then he will be logged otherwise I will redirect him to an authentication form.

I found this (http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0441.html) where a JSP page uses the NTML protocol to get the windows username. It works (only on IE). But...

... I would like to do the same but with JSF 2.0 technology (to have this information on the server side and use it for authentication).

Do you think it's possible?

I use Tomcat 7 with JDBCRealm and a FORM authentication method.

Comment: Provided that the given legacy JSP example of rgagnon.com works, just put all that Java code in a Java class (read: a JSF backing bean class) instead of a JSP file and you've the answer for JSF.

Comment: I don't understand, you're using forms *and* NTLM to do authentication?

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for your reply. With the debugger, I've seen that when I load the JSP file, it loads twice : the first one request.getHeader("Authorization") return a null string so the reponse is response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM"); and the next time, the auth String starts with NTLM and it is possible to get the windows username. So, how can I perform this 2 times query? In the JSF getName() property, if I write Map<String,String> headers = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap(); I don't have 'Authorization' info in the header.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Yes, because I want to do the following: if a windows user is already knowned by the web application (with NTLM), he can just log in with a click but if he isn't knowned or if he wants to connect with another account, the login page must appear and I use the REALM form to do that. Is it the good solution?

Comment: @user1219412:  Is there really not an NTLM authentication plugin for Tomcat?

Comment: You can authenticate your webapp against windows with [Spring Security Kerberos plugin](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos).